# Adding both textbox and textarea dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Need to add textbox and textarea dynamically to one of my forms. I found this example which works fine for adding textbox dynamically.

**Javascript**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
</div>
```

**Result**

[image]

I tried adding a textarea

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><textarea name="desc[]"></textarea></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```

to the above javascript

and to the HTML

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"></div>
    <div><textarea name="desc[]"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

but it turns out to be erroneous. How should I add a textarea along with the textbox?

**Error**

The maximum limit allowed is 10. Say I add 6 of these fields and then decide to use 5 of them. If, I remove the last (6th one in this case) all of them get removed.

**EDIT**

Link to the above code https://jsfiddle.net/x6krv00u/

** I do not know much about javascripts.**

Comment: what error/output you are getting?

Comment: @DishaV., On clicking the remove link, all textarea and textbox disappears where as it should remove only the ones needed to be removed.

Comment: @DishaV., The maximum limit allowed is 10. Say I add 6 of these fields and then decide to use 5 of them. If, I remove the last (6th one in this case) all of them get removed

Comment: there isn't parent div each adding box in your example, so you can remove through `$(this).prev().remove();
          $(this).prev().remove();
          $(this).remove();` (https://jsfiddle.net/sherali/x6krv00u/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `input` and `textarea` don't have the same parent. That's what's causing the problem.

#### This should be the DOM structure:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="mytext[]"><br>
        <textarea name="desc[]"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, the `<br>` is optional. You should probably use CSS for formatting instead.

#### Here's how you add an `input`-`textarea` pair:

```
$(wrapper).append('<div>' +
    '<input name="mytext[]"><br>' +
    '<textarea name="desc[]"></textarea>' +
    '<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>' +
'</div>');
```

#### Here's a working example, which you can copy-paste:

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="mytext[]"><br>
        <textarea name="desc[]"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div>' +
                '<input name="mytext[]"><br>' +
                '<textarea name="desc[]"></textarea>' +
                '<a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a>' +
            '</div>');
    }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>
```

Hope this helps.

**PS:** I've tried to make minimal changes to your code. There are other (better) ways of accomplishing what you want.

---

**Edit 0:** Improved formatting.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing like this

```
$(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><textarea name="desc[]"></textarea></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>');
```

And for this following should work

```
$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
    $(this).parent().remove(); // you cannot pass 'div' in parent()
});
```

Comment: yes, I added that line $(wrapper).append('<div><textarea name="desc[]"></textarea></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); after $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); and tried your code  but the problem remains.

Comment: @RnD I edited your link let me know if that works check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/a5goqqc0/)

Comment: @Minato, Bingo! I was editing the same, you are faster! @RnD all you need to do is adding parent div to your `<a>remove</a>`

Comment: @DishaV. I am not much of a designer.. so the link is after `textarea` not on its side :P... so if you include it inside the `textarea` `div` just be sure to call `remove` on the grand parent :P.. i.e. `$(this).parent().parent().remove();`

Comment: @DishaV: Removing the *grand*parent will do the trick. I've posted a working solution.